# What is the .NET Equivalent of Java's SecretKeySpec class?

Tags: c#, java, hmacsha1, one-time-password

I was provided the following code sample in Java and I'm having trouble converting it to C#. How would I go about converting this so it'll work in .NET 4.5?

```
public static String constructOTP(final Long counter, final String key) 
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, DecoderException, InvalidKeyException 
{ 
    // setup the HMAC algorithm, setting the key to use         
    final Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA512");                  

    // convert the key from a hex string to a byte array         
    final byte[] binaryKey = Hex.decodeHex(key.toCharArray());                  

    // initialize the HMAC with a key spec created from the key         
    mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(binaryKey, "HmacSHA512"));  

    // compute the OTP using the bytes of the counter         
    byte[] computedOtp = mac.doFinal(                 
    ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putLong(counter).array());  

    //         
    // increment the counter and store the new value         
    //                  

    // return the value as a hex encoded string         
    return new String(Hex.encodeHex(computedOtp));     
}
```

Here is the C# code that I've come up with thanks to Duncan pointing out the HMACSHA512 class, but I'm unable to verify the results match without installing java, which I can't do on this machine. Does this code match the above Java?

```
    public string ConstructOTP(long counter, string key)
    {
        var mac = new HMACSHA512(ConvertHexStringToByteArray(key));
        var buffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(counter);

        Array.Resize(ref buffer, 8);

        var computedOtp = mac.ComputeHash(buffer);

        var hex = new StringBuilder(computedOtp.Length * 2);

        foreach (var b in computedOtp)
            hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2", b);

        return hex.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Clarify the specific trouble you're having.  .NET has a [SHA512 class.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha512.aspx)

Comment: In C#, there's no class called SecretKeySpec or Mac. I guess I'm not understanding what the C# equivalent to those would be. This isn't remotely my area of expertise.

Comment: SecretKeySpec is [documented here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/SecretKeySpec.html).  It appears to generate a "secret key" using the named algorithm you specify.  I really have no idea how it works, but you could try obtaining some values from it, and comparing them with the output from the .NET SHA512 class, and see if they agree.

Answer (score 2):

A `SecretKeySpec` is used to convert binary input into something that is recognised by Java security providers as a key. It does little more than decorate the bytes with a little post-it note saying "*Pssst, it's an HmacSHA512 key...*".

You can basically ignore it as a Java-ism. For your .NET code, you just need to find a way of declaring what the HMAC key is. Looking at the [`HMACSHA512`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha512%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, this seems quite straight-forward. There is a constructor that takes a byte array containing your key value.